# Adding users to a group in a Forest trusted Domain

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint

I am doing a cross forest migration for DC-A to DC-Z. on DC-A there's a SharePoint 2007 and I would like migrated users on Forest -Z to access SharePoint on Forest -A.

What I have done so far is created a domain-local group called SharePoint on Forest-A and added users from Forest-Z to it. if the users in Forest Z doesn't exist in forest-A it works very well. However, if the user is migrated it won't even be added to the group. The one that'll be added is the user in Forest A instead not Z.

Why is this happening? Is there any other way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Need more details. Where did you create the domain local group called sharepoint on forest-a? On DC-a or b? Should be A. Then a global group on B that will be added to A.

How are you migrating them? Are you using "keep sid history" on them? If yes this would allow them to continue to have access to previous permissions on the old forest.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry for the very late response. I have finished the project and migrated all sharepoint to office 365.